# Sqlite query with question mark

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a table with four rows and three columns in some sample code of the iOS sqlite database.

I am fetching data from the table with the query

```
Select * from table where column_name=? ;
```

I have problem with the `column_name=?` according to the sample code: What does the `?` mean?

Is it used in incrementing the rows?

Comment: put here your column name

Comment: ? - placeholder for real value

Comment: but where it will get the real value? bcz we are not using like "%@" in string to pass real value

Comment: Exactly your question not clear so please tell me what you wanna exactly.. ?

Comment: I just want to know what this query will give output and why we use "?" in Sqlite

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ? is a placeholder for a real value, a value you must bind to the compiled statement. [The SQLite doc on Binding Values](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) goes into detail concerning the bind.

The reason you bind values rather than just put them in the query string is because it protects from sql injection attacks - which could happen if you're using values provided directly from the user.

Answer (score 4):

The `?` represents a placeholder that you'll bind with a value (e.g. to set a text value, use `sqlite3_bind_text` after you `sqlite3_prepare_v2` the statement, but before you perform it with `sqlite3_step`.

See [`sqlite3_bind`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) documentation.

This is a very important construct to know and to use, because you never want to build your SQL using `stringWithFormat`. By using `sqlite3_bind`, you save yourself from having to write code that escapes any quotation marks you might have in your input, e.g. you're trying to insert values of `Joe's Bar and Grill` (where the apostrophe will mess up your SQL if you're using single quotation marks) or `Dwayne "The Rock" Johnson` (where the quotes will mess up your SQL if you're using double quotation marks). It also protects you against SQL injection attacks. Definitely use `sqlite3_bind` rather than building SQL statements manually.

Answer (score 1):

"?" is used for...

This usually implies a prepared statement, where the parameters are filled in later.
(see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statements#Parameterized_statements).

OR

In some statements, parameters are unknown when the statement is prepared because a different value can be inserted each time the statement is executed. In these statements, you can use a question-mark ( ? ) placeholder where a parameter must be supplied when the statement is executed.

OR

Although PreparedStatement objects can be used for SQL statements with no parameters, you probably use them most often for SQL statements that take parameters. The advantage of using SQL statements that take parameters is that you can use the same statement and supply it with different values each time you execute it.